# Testing Stored procedure correctness

Tags: unit-testing, stored-procedures

Suppose you have 2 stored procedure, let's say a `GetProducts` and a `GetProductDetails`.
Now, the GetProducts returns a list of products with a property that is "calculated" basing on additional calculation (the last time it was purchased, the number of resellers etc).

How can I be sure about the correctness of the data returned?

Do I have to call the GetProducts, then for each product call the GetProductDetails and finally check the correctness for each result?
Or do I have to call the GetProductDetails only for a randomic product(s)?

Comment: Consider moving those stored procedures into your application or a data access layer.  It's easier to test there, and easier to maintain there.  Reserve stored procedures for things that need to run on the server, things like accounting reconciliations or statistical rollups.

Comment: As to your specific questions about GetProducts and GetProductDetails, I don't write unit tests for things like that (CRUD operations are unremarkable, from a programming perspective), but that's probably because I use an ORM to retrieve individual entities.

Comment: Right, but my whole application is based on stored procedures (trust me, there are reasons for not accessing directly the tables).

Comment: You can use *views* to restrict access to tables.

Comment: It is basically as simple as the answer, but probably you don't know how to apply it to your case. So the actual question is not only about _testing_ your procedures. The conventional approach is that the application is written and stored separately from the production environment, then it is built, tested, and all of that happens in isolation from the production instance and then it is deployed. I can imagine there may be questions how to do all of that for a database, but guessing them would not be useful. So maybe you refine your question and specify which step you have difficulties with.

Comment: How about initializing your test database with a known set of products and known values of the calculated properties for those products. Your test can then call the stored procedure and as test the return values against expected values.

The initialization data could contain a collection of trivial and edge cases. And, if you find any issue with the stored procedure later in the future, you could add more cases to the initialization data to cover those cases.

Answer (score 2):

You test the correctness (in a unit test, I suppose) the same way you would do it in any other layer: you provide some test data where you exactly know what the outcome of the calculation should be, then you write a unit test for `GetProducts` using this test data, and verify if the returned result matches the expected result.

There are two things which can make this harder in stored procedures than in other mainstream application programming languages:

1. the (non-)availability of a convenient unit testing framework
2. the (non-)availability of callback mechanisms which allow things like dependency injection

The first point can be mitigated by building your own unit testing infrastructure to the degree you need it, which is usually not too hard. For the second point, there are workarounds like [this one](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/03/07/dependency-injection-in-plsql-remove-hard-coded-dependencies-from-your-code/).

Comment: "you provide some test data where you exactly know what the outcome of the calculation should be" is fine for "pure" functions, but for data that change over time is impossible. I mean, today the Product #1 may have 2 resellers, tomorrow 5. So, if I make the expected result "static", today the test may pass and tomorrow it may fail.

Comment: @Bellons No, it won't. The resellers are part of the test data.

Comment: @Bellons: test data should be stored in test database, apart from production, with controlled changes to the data. And a well known principle for unit tests is to make sure each tests always works with a defined input. I thought this was so obvious that I did not see any necessity to mention it.

Comment: "a well known principle for unit tests is to make sure each tests always works with a defined input" is exactly the part I'm referring. I've always thought that was referred to functions like _find the sum of two integers_ or _find the minimal path in a graph_. But data on DB are meant to change over time.

The purpose of unit testing is to test small pieces of code, isn't it? So you are testing functionalities, not data (even if in a test environment).

Comment: A solution could be the usage of a throwaway db that creates data with expected properties in a "sandbox" environment. That way the stored could be tested with real input data and a real expected result, independent of the status of the whole system.

Comment: @Bellons: yes, throwaway DBs is one possible way of approaching this. But it is often possible to get away with something simpler, like a test data script for each unit tests which clears and refills certain tables in the database before the test starts. Which route to go depends heavily on the DBMS and the architecture of the system.